# How preventing Watir to open brower?

Tags: google-chrome, web-scraping, webdriver, watir

I am using the following to scrape a page. Scraper works fine however each time I run it, it opens a Chrome Window which I don't need.

```
browser = Watir::Browser.new

loginpage = browser.goto('https://www.login-page.com')
```

How to prevent it to open the Window?

Comment: If you don't run the first line, it wouldn't open the new window, exclude the first line from second time onwards .

Answer (score 1):

I think browser showing is expected behaviour, you might want not to see it though.

This worked fine, and no browser or window were "opened".

```
b = Watir::Browser.new :chrome, headless: true   
puts "Browser is opened." 
loginpage = b.goto "www.google.com"  
puts "Navigate to google, title is #{b.title}"
```

this works aswell

```
b = Watir::Browser.new :chrome, :switches => %w[--headless]  
puts "Browser is opened." 
loginpage = b.goto "www.google.com"  
puts "Navigate to google, title is #{b.title}"
```

Hope thats the case.

Edit:

if you're running tests on linux this might be worth trying

run Xvfb from command line

```
Xvfb :12 -screen 0 1680x1080x16 &
```

then in your tests, set that display before initializing browser

```
ENV['DISPLAY'] = ':12'
#or this
#`export DISPLAY=:12`
```

if that doesn't work, I'm out of guesses.

Comment: I've tried both and neither options work. The browser won't open, that is true. But the scrapper doesn't work anymore. While it works well without headless...